# Multiple Reciever for same action in GCM across the applications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When we implement GCM(Google cloud messaging) in android we have to give our receiver in every application. according to my knowledge if you have multiple app having its own receiver mapped for common action `"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"`. Receiver inside every application should call but not, I want to know how android identify that which application's receiver should call ?

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I dont think so the app with specific app name only recieves the specific broadcast

Comment: okay according to you all receiver of the common action will call, but I think it is not done in case of GCM.

Comment: are you talking about other broadcast receivers like message received or call received broadcasts.

Comment: No I am talking in context of GCM only

Comment: that what i said it identify with package name of the application. If I am wrong, sorry i never get your question

Comment: Accroding to your previous comment all app having reciever mapped with common action will start I am satisfiy with it but in case of GCM all app's receiver haveing action with "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" should start but it does not happen. This is my question why ? please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48371/discussion-between-coolmonster-and-user2130718)

Answer (score 1):

When you specify your package name in the `category` of the intent filter of the GCM broadcast receiver, you narrow down the scope of the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` action to the specific application that the GCM message should be delivered to.